# How to combine a set of "blocks" without gaps

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, permutation, combinatorics

I need to write a function which take as a parameter an array "blocks".
"Blocks" are presented as objects containing block's identificator and geometric representation of form where 0 - gap, 1 - content.
All blocks have same width within a set, any set cotains blocks which can be placed without gaps.

The function should return set of blocks without gaps. It is possible to rotate blocks and change their order in the set.
I hope some examples below will help.

Updated:
The blocks flow from up to down, i.e. a block with resulted position 1 is below the block position 2

Example 1

```
const blocks = [{
    "id": 738,
    "form": [
      [1, 0],
      [1, 1]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 841,
    "form": [
      [1, 1],
      [0, 1]
    ]
}];

const result = [
  {
    "blockId": 738,
    "position": 1,
    "isRotated": false
  },
  {
    "blockId": 841,
    "position": 2,
    "isRotated": false
  }
];
```

Example 2

```
const blocks = [{
    "id": 443,
    "form": [
      [1, 0, 1],
      [1, 1, 1]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 327,
    "form": [
      [0, 1, 0],
      [1, 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 0],
      [0, 1, 0]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 891,
    "form": [
      [0, 0, 1],
      [1, 0, 1],
      [1, 1, 1]
    ]
}];

const result = [
  {
    "blockId": 443,
    "position": 1,
    "isRotated": false
  },
  {
    "blockId": 327,
    "position": 2,
    "isRotated": true
  },
  {
    "blockId": 891,
    "position": 3,
    "isRotated": true
  }
];
```

Example 3

```
    const blocks = [{
        "id": 4892,
        "form": [
          [0, 0, 1],
          [1, 0, 1],
          [1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1]
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 1839,
        "form": [
          [1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1],
          [1, 0, 0]
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 8183,
        "form": [
          [0, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 0],
          [0, 1, 0]
        ]
    }];

const result = [
  {
    "blockId": 4892,
    "position": 1,
    "isRotated": false
  },
  {
    "blockId": 8183,
    "position": 2,
    "isRotated": false
  },
  {
    "blockId": 1839,
    "position": 3,
    "isRotated": false
  }
];
```

Example 4

```
const blocks = [{
    "id": 1,
    "form": [
      [1, 0, 1],
      [1, 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 1]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "form": [
      [0, 0, 1],
      [1, 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 1]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "form": [
      [0, 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 1],
      [0, 1, 0]
    ]
}];

const result = [
  {
    "blockId": 1,
    "position": 1,
    "isRotated": false
  },
  {
    "blockId": 3,
    "position": 2,
    "isRotated": false
  },
  {
    "blockId": 2,
    "position": 3,
    "isRotated": true
  }
];
```

I tried to deal with form arrays as matrices, but did not find a solution.

My code:

```
const first ={
    "id": 443,
    "form": [
      [1, 0, 1],
      [1, 1, 1]
    ]
  }

  const second ={
    "id": 113,
    "form": [
      [1, 1, 1],
      [1, 1, 0]
    ]
  }

function rotateBlock(block){
    rotatedBlock = {...block, "form": block["form"].reverse()};
    return block;
}

console.log(rotateBlock(first))
console.log(rotateBlock(second))
//output:
//{ id: 443, form: [ [ 1, 1, 1 ], [ 1, 0, 1 ] ] }
//{ id: 113, form: [ [ 1, 1, 0 ], [ 1, 1, 1 ] ] }

const first ={
    "id": 443,
    "form": [
      [1, 0, 1],
      [1, 1, 1]
    ]
  }

  const second ={
    "id": 113,
    "form": [
      [1, 1, 1],
      [0, 1, 0]
    ]
  }

function checkBlocks(block1, block2){

    const arr1=block1["form"]
    const arr2=block2["form"]

const topFirst=arr1[0] //top of first
const invertedTopFirst = topFirst.map(el=>{
    if (el===1){return el = 0} else return el=1;
})

const bottomSecond = arr2[arr2.length -1]//bottom of second
return JSON.stringify(invertedTopFirst) === JSON.stringify(bottomSecond)
}

console.log(checkBlocks(first, second));
//output:
//true
```

Comment: `I tried` post what you tried.  Explain what didn’t work.  At the moment this is a request for someone to do your project.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and learn [ask]. Your questions seems to be interesting, but it is currently impossible to answer. The requirements are not clear. Also, you are supposed to include your best attempt so far to resolve the problem by yourself.

Comment: Some questions that come to my mind: 1) every block can have 3 possible rotations, but your field `isRotated` only expects "true", which doesn't tell how it should be rotated. 2) there are multiple possible solutions for every set of blocks, so it is not clear which of them should be selected. 3) There might not be any solution, so what is expected to happen in that case? 4) is the order of elements important in the result array? because your first example seems to be out of order

Comment: Even if you are not able to fully resolve your problem, you are expected to show effort, and we help you from there. Start by writing separate functions for each small piece of the solution. Write a function that rotates a block, and another function that takes 2 blocks and check if they match.

Comment: @James That case that I spent all day and did not write something valuable. I don't understand how to deal with the task and ask about help, don't want you do my project.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues Thank you for your response. Some thoughts about the questions:
1) every block has only 2 possible "isRotated" value - true - if rotated by 180 degree, no - original without rotation.
2) it might be any possible
3) there should be solution 100% - the set prepared to fill without gaps
4) the order does matter: the blocks flow from up to down, i.e. a block with resulted position 1 is below the block position 2. Thank you for this, updated my description.
But the main problem for me - order of blocks in initial array might be different than in resulted.

Comment: Can you try to implement the two functions I mentioned in my last comment? With those two, I can help you to try different arranges.

Comment: @Rodrigo Rodrigues I am trying to solve the task.  I will write my code and place here. I did not write any code because I don't know how to deal with the "form". I don't want someone does my project. I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: By "comparing blocks if they match" I didn't mean to check if they are equal, I meant to check if they can combine without gap.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues My bad, I will refactor it. I guess I am starting to understand how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to split you problem into smaller tasks and have a function to handle each of them, then ultimately combine all together to achieve the expected result.

### The solution

See below a suggested implementation of your requirement. I am adding notes below with comments.

```
// Full solution
const rotate = form => form.map(r => [...r].reverse()).reverse()
const splice = (arr, i) => [...arr.slice(0, i), ...arr.slice(i + 1)]
const attach = (stack, blockId, isRotated = false) => 
  [...stack, { blockId, position: stack.length + 1, isRotated }]
const match = (f1, f2) => {
  for (var n1 = 0; n1 < f1.length; n1++) if (f1.at(n1).every(x => x)) break
  for (var n2 = f2.length; n2 > 0; n2--) if (f2.at(n2 - 1).every(x => x)) break
  return n1 + n2 == f2.length 
    && f2.slice(n2).every((r, i) => r.every((x, j) => x ^ f1[i][j]))
}
function* assemble(stock, stack = [], slot = []) {
  if (stock.length)
    for (const [i, { id, form }] of stock.entries()) {
      if (match(slot, form))
        yield* assemble(splice(stock, i), attach(stack, id), form)
      if (match(slot, rotate(form)))
        yield* assemble(splice(stock, i), attach(stack, id, true), rotate(form))
    }
  else if (match(slot, [])) yield stack 
}

// Example of usage:
for (const stack of assemble(blocks2)) {
  stack.forEach(b => console.log(b))
  break
}
// {blockId: 443, position: 1, isRotated: false}
// {blockId: 327, position: 2, isRotated: true}
// {blockId: 891, position: 3, isRotated: true}
```

### Notes

- `rotate`: a simple function that completely reverses the a nested array (like the forms).
  For example: `rotate([[0,1],[1,1]])` returns `[[1,1],[1,0]]`.
- `splice`: auxiliary function to shallow copy an array except the value at index `i`.
  Example: `splice([0,10,20,30], 2)` returns `[0,10,30]`.
- `attach`: will append a new value to the result "stack" of blocks, converting it to the format expected in the question. Returns the resulting stack.
  Example: `attach([], 99, true})` returns `[{blockId:99,position:1,isRotated:true}]`
- `match`: takes 2 forms `f1,f2` and check if `f2`'s bottom part can match `f1`'s top part without gaps. For it, it scans each line of `f1` from top to bottom and stops when it finds the a line with all ones. The scanned part will be the "matching area". Then, does the same for `f2`, but from bottom to top.
  The idea is to match each element in both areas, and apply the [bitwise xor (^)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_XOR) operation on then: it will result true only if one is `1` and the other is `0`. If it is true for every elements in both areas, they match.

### Assumptions

It is worth to mention that this solution makes the following assumptions about the input blocks:

1. the only possible elements in the forms are `0` or `1`.
2. a block always have a form, and it will never contain full-zero lines or "holes" (like `[[1,1],[0,1],[1,1]]`).
3. all rows have the same width in a form, and all blocks in a set have forms with the same width.
4. block ids don't repeat.
5. there are only 2 possible rotations: not-rotated and 180º (not mirror).

---

### The algorithm

All that said, here is the approach applied in the `assemble` function:

The functions receives at least the argument `stock` (the available blocks to pick from). The other arguments are the `stack` (combined blocks so far) and the `slot` (the form of the previously attached block).

If the stock is not empty (`if (stock.length)`), enumerate all its elements (deconstruct it's  { `id`, `form` }) together with its index `i` in the stock array. It then iterates over the blocks available in stock, and on each iteration, it checks if the currently picked form matches the previous slot. (Actually, it tries twice: once without rotation and once with rotation).

For each block that matches, it calls the `assemble` function again recursively, with the current block removed from the stock and attached to the stack. By doing so, it will reduce the stock on each step until exhaustion. When the stock is empty, it means we've been able to successfully assemble using all the blocks and without gaps. At this point, the function yields a value (the current stack).

I implemented this function as a generator (that is why it `yield` instead of `return`). This way, you can decide if you want to stop at the first iteration that yields a value (for example, by putting a `break` inside the `for of` loop, or continue listing all the valid solutions.

### Caution

Eventually, if you don't break and let the algorithm find more answers, it will try all possible permutations of matching blocks. **Be aware** that it could mean an **astronomical** number or recursive calls to the function.

The upper bound of the number of iterations, in the worst case, is ***2<sup>n</sup>⋅n!*** (where `n` is the number of blocks). And that is the maximum number of times the function yields a value -- the upper bound number of actual calls to the function is ***∑<sub>i=0..n</sub> 2<sup>i</sup>⋅n!/(n-i)!***.

That means, if you have **10 blocks**:

- the function `assemble` could be called up to `6,126,468,861` times.
- the number of solutions is up to `3,715,891,200`.
- you will be doing a proportional number of iterations over the elements of the forms to compare and to reverse.

The good news is: you will hardly experience numbers like those in real cases. The worst case is when all blocks in the set are perfectly rectangular with no dents, so all permutations would be valid answers. In real cases, most of the blocks will have dents in at least one side. Also, although the time to find all solutions can be huge, the time to find just one solution is much much smaller. And for the cases where not solution can be found, the worst cases are also silly scenarios, like all not-dented except one.

The algorithm could be improved by adding some heuristics in order to detect cases without solution, like count the number of "cap" blocks (the ones that can be used as first or last), as they need to be even. Furthermore, the number of recursions could be greatly reduced by applying a caching mechanism ([memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)).

That is all to say that this code, as it is, does not scale well and might not be suitable for a big number of blocks. And, unless strictly necessary, avoid trying to find all solutions.

### Examples

```js
const blocks1 = [
  { id: 738, form: [[1, 0], [1, 1]] },
  { id: 841, form: [[1, 1], [0, 1]] }
]
const blocks2 = [
  { id: 443, form: [[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]] },
  { id: 327, form: [[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]] },
  { id: 891, form: [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]] }
]
const blocks3 = [
  { id: 4892, form: [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]] }, 
  { id: 1839, form: [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0]] }, 
  { id: 8183, form: [[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0]] }
]
const blocks4 = [
  {id: 1, form: [[1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]] },
  {id: 2, form: [[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1],  [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]] },
  {id: 3, form: [[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0]]}
]
const rotate = form => form.map(r => [...r].reverse()).reverse()
const splice = (arr, i) => [...arr.slice(0, i), ...arr.slice(i + 1)]
const attach = (stack, blockId, isRotated = false) => 
  [...stack, { blockId, position: stack.length + 1, isRotated }]
const match = (f1, f2) => {
  for (var n1 = 0; n1 < f1.length; n1++) if (f1.at(n1).every(x => x)) break
  for (var n2 = f2.length; n2 > 0; n2--) if (f2.at(n2 - 1).every(x => x)) break
  return n1 + n2 == f2.length 
    && f2.slice(n2).every((r, i) => r.every((x, j) => x ^ f1[i][j]))
}
function* assemble(stock, stack = [], slot = []) {
  if (stock.length)
    for (const [i, { id, form }] of stock.entries()) {
      if (match(slot, form))
        yield* assemble(splice(stock, i), attach(stack, id), form)
      if (match(slot, rotate(form)))
        yield* assemble(splice(stock, i), attach(stack, id, true), rotate(form))
    }
  else if (match(slot, [])) yield stack
}
console.log("Example 1:")
for (const result of assemble(blocks1)) {
  result.forEach(b => console.log(JSON.stringify(b)))
  break
}
console.log("Example 2:")
for (const result of assemble(blocks2)) {
  result.forEach(b => console.log(JSON.stringify(b)))
  break
}
console.log("Example 3:")
for (const result of assemble(blocks3)) {
  result.forEach(b => console.log(JSON.stringify(b)))
  break
}
console.log("Example 4:")
for (const result of assemble(blocks4)) {
  result.forEach(b => console.log(JSON.stringify(b)))
  break
}
console.log("All solutions of Example 4:")
for (const result of assemble(blocks4)) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
}
```